# white line on my photo different exposure

Tags: exposure, lighting, fujifilm

i got this bright and dark line difference since last 5 months and it happens often but not always
is there something broken in my image processor or what 
im using fujifilm xt100 and fx 35mm
changing shutter speed doesnt solve the problem 
I need help :( [image: first photo in this photo im using F4.0 iso 200 shuter speed 1/100 with led light as a backgroud light]
first photo in this photo im using F4.0 iso 200 shuter speed 1/100 with led light as a backgroud light

second photo 1/60 f8.0 iso 2500 natural light

third photo F16 1/100 iso 200 natural light

[image: second photo 1/60 f8.0 iso 2500 natural light]

[image: F16 1/100 iso 200 natural light]

Comment: What is the shutter speed? What is the light source? (LED? Fluorescent? Incandescent?)

Comment: @raviputcha - Perhaps it wasn't clear to the OP as to what effort was required to understand the problem and that may have been the reason for the omission of exposure details and light source.

Comment: in this photo im using F4.0 iso 200 shuter speed 1/100 with led light as a backgroud light

Comment: the problem here is the line is permanent and it doesnt change when i move the camera

Comment: The third photo doesn't use any artificial light and sad same issue is apparent. Are 2nd and 3rd photo made with camera rotated 180 degrees, thus is the brightness border at the same position?

Comment: Yes i guess the problem is with the shutter closing speed

Comment: @Marcellus It's far more likely the first curtain is opening too slowly over the last one-third of the frame than that the second curtain is closing too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your first shutter curtain is dragging the last one-third of the frame or so when opening. This causes the interval between the first and second curtain to be shorter for that part of the sensor than for the rest of the sensor.